# programmatically determine Oracle Home installed version?

Tags: c#, windows, oracle, remote-registry

I need to determine from a program what version of Oracle is installed in each of the Oracle Homes on a server.  As there may not be any databases created in the Home yet, I need to be able to do this outside of the database (i.e., without connecting to the database).  Also, it would be highly preferable to be able to do this from a remote program.

This is from a windows program running .Net (C#, if that matters).

I am currently reading remote registry keys (using this technique: [How to Read Remote Registry Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566547/how-to-read-remote-registry-keys)), to find all of the Oracle Homes according to [this method](https://community.oracle.com/thread/351127?start=0&tstart=0).  This works fine, however, I have looked around those keys and do not see any information on the exact version/release.

The name of an Oracle Home itself is of course 1) not a reliable indicator and 2) does not have the exact version/release (for instance "10.2.0.4.0").  Basically I am looking for a way to figure out what the Oracle Universal Installer tells you in the Installed Products button.

Answer (score 3):

Search for file `oci.dll` in `PATH`, this is one of the major files of an Oracle Client installation. You can read version of this file with `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("oci.dll");`

In order the get the Registry Hive, search for file `oracle.reg` in PATH (i.e. Oracle Home). This file is a simple text file containing the Registry key, for example `SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1`. You will find related registry values in `HK_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1`
`

Comment: Do you mean in `ORACLE_Home\bin`?

Comment: I just checked and this does not match what Universal Installer says.  Example: Ora10g home has 10.2.0.1.0 installed and applied patch set 3 so that the resulting version is 10.2.0.4.0.  However, OCI.DLL FileVersion property says "10.2.0.1.0".

Comment: Yes, there you will find it.

Comment: Are you really interested in the Patch level? Usually mayor and minor version (e.g. 10.2) should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I really do need it.  It's the kind of thing that we frequently have to check for product compatibility issues when planning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't be exact, but i think you should try to look into `v$parameter` system view.

Comment: How would I look at that for a Home without a database?  That's what I am asking for...

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the oracle home path given in the registry and try to execute below command in the command prompt if the home is in Windows

```
    $ORACLE_HOME\OPatch\opatch lsinventory | find "Oracle Database"
```